# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for 2 different domains or sub-domains CORS issue

Tags: javascript, cors, access-control, openseadragon

There are a lot o topics about 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', but I couldn't find one for Openseadragon which is for sub-domain name. My website is **exampple.domain.com** trying to open DZI from **anotherexampple.domain.com** and I have an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load **anotherexampple.domain.com/123.dzi**.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '**exampple.domain.com**' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Both websites are using the same protocol HTTPS, and server is IIS

Server for **exampple.domain.com** is set up with:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

And server for **anotherexampple.domain.com** is set up with:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.domain.com

Also, openseadragon has settings:

```
crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous',
ajaxWithCredentials: false,
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix CORS issue for same domain with different sub-domains? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: "Can somebody tell me how to fix CORS issue for same domain with different sub-domains?" — The same way you fix cross-origin issues for any other pair of origins that are not the same as each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.domain.com
> ```

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header doesn't support *partial* wildcards.

Either use `*` or the full origin name.

You can read the `Origin` request header, pattern match it, and then echo it out on the server if you want to whitelist everything on a particular domain.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You might have *tried* to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but it clearly hasn't worked. You need to reexamine your configuration.

Comment: I changed it, and still doesn't work. But thank you for letting me know. This was silly mistake.

Comment: and where does this line go?

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy — What line?

Answer (score 0):

This link has a nice explanation for possible values for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. unfortunately you do not have much options, other than '*' or single domain like 'http://example.com'

https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/